# Preserve raw text file newlines with scrapy

Tags: scrapy, screen-scraping

When I scrape a raw text file, e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/master/Gulpfile.js scrapy ignores line breaks and saves the content as a text blob. Is there a way to preserve the `\n` characters?

I've tried using these commands with no luck:

```
response.css("body p::text").extract_first()
response.css("body p").xpath("text()").extract_first()
response.css("body p").xpath("string()").extract_first()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you saving response to a file?

Comment: scrapy doesn't ignore `\n` can you share your pipelines?

Comment: I'm saving the content to a mysql table via Django. If scrapy preserves newlines then it sounds like the transfer to a table field is stripping them.

Comment: Scrapy uses [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It should be easy to provide an example that shows line breaks being deleted (or not).